# Random number seed overlapping issue

Tags: matlab, simulation, gpu, random-seed

I am using Matlab GPU computing to run a simulation. I suspect I may encounter a "random number seed" overlapping issue. My code is the following

```
N = 10000;
v = rand(N,1);
p = [0:0.1:1];
pA = [0:0.1:2];
[v,p,pA] = ndgrid(v,p,pA);
v = gpuArray(v);
p = gpuArray(p);
pA = gpuArray(pA);
t = 1;
bH = 0.9;
bL = 0.6;
a = 0.5;

Y = MyFunction(v,p,pA,t,bH,bL,a);

function[RA] = MyFunction(v,p,pA,t,bH,bL,a)
function[RA] = SSP1(v,p,pA)
RA = 0;
S1 = rand;
S2 = rand;
S3 = rand;
vA1 = (S1<a)*bH+(S1>=a)*bL;
vA2 = (S2<a)*bH+(S2>=a)*bL;
vA3 = (S3<a)*bH+(S3>=a)*bL;

if p<=t && pA>3*bL && pA<=3*bH 
   if pA>vA1+vA2+vA3
      if v>=p
         RA = p;
      end
   else
      if v+vA1+vA2+vA3>=p+pA
         RA = p+pA;
      end
   end
end
end
[RA] = gather(arrayfun(@SSP1,v,p,pA));
end
```

The idea of the code is the following:

I generate `N` random agents, which is characterized by the value of `v`. Then for each agent, I have to compute a quantity given `(p,pA)`. As I have `N` agents and many combinations of `(p,pA)`, I want to use GPU to speed up the process. ***But here comes a tricky thing:***

for each agent, in order to finish my computation, I have to generate 3 extra random variables, `vA1,vA2,vA3`. Based on my understanding of GPU (I could be wrong), it does these computations simultaneously, i.e, for each agent `v`, it generates 3 random variables `vA1,vA2,vA3`. And GPU does this `N` procedures at the same time. However, I am not sure whether for agent 1 and agent 2, the corresponding `vA1,vA2,vA3` may overlap? Because here `N` could be 1 million. I want to make sure that for all of these agents, the random number seed that is used to generate their corresponding `vA1,vA2,vA3` won't overlap; otherwise, I am in big trouble.

There is a way to prevent this from happening, which is: I first generate `3N` of these random variables `vA1,vA2,vA3`. Then I put them into my GPU. However, that may require a lot of GPU memory, which I don't have. The current method, I guess does not need too much GPU memory, as I am generating `vA1,vA2,vA3` on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

What you say does not happen. The proof is that the following code snipped generates random values in `hB`.

```
A=ones(100,1);

dA=gpuArray(A);

[hB] = gather(arrayfun(@applyrand,dA));
function dB=applyrand(dA)
r=rand;
dB=dA*r;
end
```

That said, your code has only 12 values for your random variables (4 for each) because for your use of S1, S2 and S3 you are basically flipping a coin:

```
vA1 = (S1<0.5)*bH+(S1>=0.5)*bL;
```

so `vA1` is either 0, `bH`, `bL` or `bH+bL`.
Maybe this lack of variability is what is making you think that you don't have much randomness, not very clear from the question.